# AppleScript count text assurance

Tags: date, text, count, applescript

My script is saving texts

```
set dataBackupFile to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Note_Backup.txt"
```

It's time I run the script, this added the date

```
set myDate to date string of (current date)
set myTime to time string of (current date)

set myDateTime to "--------------------------------------------------------------
" & myDate & " - " & myTime & "
```

Result :

> Wednesday 9 November 2016 -

How can I get AppleScript to count how many time this date is listed on the text file, so I can added to the title

E.g : 
Wednesday 9 November 2016 - (2)

My script :

```
set myDate to date string of (current date)
set filetocheck to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Note_Backup.txt"
set counter to (count text items of myDate) of filetocheck
```

But the result is 25, while the real result on the files is 38.

The text to count is in this format (Wednesday 9 November 2016):

---

Wednesday 9 November 2016 -- 10:10:54 - 1 (-41)

0000 other data here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with text item delimiters, replace `linefeed` with `return` if the line delimiter characters are `\r`

```
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "--" & linefeed & date string of (current date)}
set counter to (count text items of myDateTime) - 1
set text item delimiters to TID
```

`counter` will contain the number of occurrences

To check your text file use

```
set myDate to date string of (current date)
set filetocheck to (path to desktop folder as text) & "Note_Backup.txt"
set theText to read file filetocheck
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, "--" & linefeed & date string of (current date)}
set counter to (count text items of theText) - 1
set text item delimiters to TID
```

Comment: Sorry I feel stupid but I didn't managed to set the source and the text delimiters , I added set filetocheck to (path to desktop folder as text) & "_Note_Backup.txt"